# Stretching a HTML Input Box alongside additional input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, user-interface, input

I'm using jQuery on this site, which has form inputs. I'd like one particular field to get longer (width) as the user enters data and space runs out.

**How can I calculate when I *ACTUALLY* need to make the input (`type="text"`) longer?**  What works for one browser may not work for all browsers.

**Is this something that can't be calculated, so everybody does it based on trial and error within each browser?**  Will I need to resort to this and tweak stretch values with a .keyup() that checks the value?.. EG..

```
$(".stretchInput").keyup( function(event) {
   var someValueAdjustedByTrialAndError = 30;
   var stretchPastLength = someValueAdjustedByTrialAndError;
   var stretchBy = 5;
   var baseWidth = 100;
   if ($(this).val().length > stretchPastLength ) {
      $(this).css('width',(baseWidth + ($(this).val().length - stretchPastLength ) * stretchBy ) + 'px');
   } else {
      $(this).css('width','');
   }
});
```

Comment: the solution you're looking for is quite a big undertaking. Have you considered the trick the stackoverflow uses on this very site after you begin typing in the Search input field?

Comment: While that's probably the best solution if mine doesn't ultimately work (just go to a certain generous length), I don't have enough space to assume I can be generous.. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATED to detect backspace]

Place a hidden `<span>` element on the page, and within the `keyup` event of your `<input>` field you can mirror the input value in your span. Update the input field width to match your span.

**Html:**

```
<span style="display:none"></span>
<input type="text" style="width:100px"; />
```

Note the `min-width` value on the input element that is there to prevent the width from shrinking below a certain value.

**jQuery:**

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var $span = $('span');
    var $this = $(this);
    $span.text($this.val()); 
    $this.width($span.width());
});
```

Comment: REALLY good answer.  All I have to do is make sure the Span has the same CSS settings, and I can mimic its length.  Even smaller JS footprint, too. :D

Answer (score 2):

## Solution for TextAreas

#### Description

This sounds like you want a *auto growing textarea* like on facebook. If so
**why reinvent the wheel** ? 
I encorage you to use the wonderful `Elasting jQuery Plugin`.

> Elastic makes your textareas grow and shrink to fit it’s content. It was inspired by the auto growing textareas on Facebook. The major difference between Elastic and it’s competitors is it’s weight.

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/r3Ekw/)
- [jQuery Elastic Plugin](http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)

## Solution for Text Inputs

Here my solution for `input` elements.

The problem is that the width of a char is not *evenly* on every font.

If you choose courier as the font, you can make it perfect.

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<input class="stretchInput" style="font-family: courier"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
var initialWidth = $(".stretchInput").width();
$(".stretchInput").keyup( function(event) {
   var charWidth = 8.5;
   var width = $(this).val().length*charWidth;
   if ($(this).width() < width)
   {
       $(this).width(width);
   } else {
       $(this).width(initialWidth );
   }
});
```

## Check out my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2v8yA/2/)

Comment: So close-- SO close. This works with textareas, primarily because textareas change HEIGHT... But what I'm looking for is WIDTH, since I'm working with an input element.. :/  (Def +1 for my future use, though.)  (Also: editing my question. I did specifically say 'textbox', which is not what I meant.. Apologies)

Comment: Accepting because your answer presupposed the same thing that @BumbleB2na is saying--that there's almost no way to calculate character width in an input field, and just to wing it.

Comment: Thank for the accept. Check out my answer again. If you choose `courier` as the font and `8.5` as the charWidth you will get the best result.

Glad to help! Have a nice day!